# Wordpress Site transfered to another Server. 404 all pages

Tags: 404-error, migration

I transfered a Wordpress page to new Server, and now all pages are 404.
I tried this solution https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/

but still nothing is fixed...
Is there any other solutions?

Thank you in Advance...

Comment: can you edit your question to include details of how you performed this transfer? Are you sure rewrite rules/HTAccess/Nginx configs are all setup to allow pretty permalinks and that you've enabled them in settings? Right now there is not enough information to diagnose the problem or provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had 5.5 version of wordpress and it was Incompatible with 8 PHP (on new server) so I updated Wordpress to 6.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but here is a suggestion. What have you done so far? I recently moved a site successfully like this:

1. Dump DB
2. In the Dump, replace every occurence of the old site URL by the new site URL.
3. Copy over the entire directory
4. Fit the configuration `wp-config.php` (DB access, site URL, TLS proxy)
5. Replay the modified dump in the new database
6. Load WordPress
7. Flush all caches, if there are some

Note that points 2 and 4 are crucial.